# Check if URL is a torrent in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, bittorrent

What's the best way for me to take url like: http://foobar.com/foo.torrent and check if that really is a torrent, not a html page or something else funny.
Suggestions?
Thank you :)

Comment: Why all the down-votes? I thought it was a relevant question.

Comment: I think some people see the word ‘torrent’ and immediately go “piracy am bad” and downvote.

Answer (score 11):

To check the type of a resource without downloading it, use a HEAD request:

```
WebRequest request= WebRequest.Create("http://foobar.com/foo.torrent");
request.Method= "HEAD";
WebResponse response= request.GetResponse();
if (response.Headers.Get("Content-Type")=="application/x-bittorrent") {
    ...
```

However, the type `application/x-bittorrent` might not be set up in some servers, so it's possible you might get `application/octet-stream` instead, or even `text/plain` if you are unlucky. If you need to account for this, about all you could do would be to fetch the file with a normal GET request, and see if you can decode it.

The BitTorrent file format is based around a format called ‘bencode’. [Here's](http://code.google.com/p/bencode-net/) a .NET library that claims to handle it. You can guess any file that's valid bencode is a torrent file, but if you want to make sure you can look at the mapping it decodes to and check for the `info` and `announce` properties.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to know if it's really a torrent file is to download it and check if it's a [torrent file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torrent_file).

Answer (score 3):

Probably best to download and validate it and/ or check the content type is `application/x-bittorrent`.

Comment: Note that many web-servers don't serve files with the right content-type. So if the web-servers returns the content-type `"application/octet-stream"` it's still not impossible that the file is a torrent file.

Answer (score 1):

Read the torrent file specification, then write a C# app to download the contents of the URL and see if it meets the rules in the specification.

Answer (score 1):

In additon to the good answer bobince provided, you could also have a look at the [monotorrent](http://projects.qnetp.net/projects/show/monotorrent) open source  c# implementation. They download the whole .torrent file and parse the bencode afterwards (cf.: http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/bitsharp/src/MonoTorrent/MonoTorrent.Common/Torrent.cs lines 611ff)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [MonoTorrent](http://monotorrent.com) library. Specifically, you could use the static method

```
Torrent.TryLoad(Uri url, string location, out Torrent torrent)
```

which will return a boolean value indicating whether the `url` parameter points to a valid torrent file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to learn some c++ you could make a external call to the [libtorrent](http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/) library with a P/Invoke I am shure it has a way to validate files.